# replace method in linked list with some errors

Tags: java, replace, linked-list

I need to create a method that goes through all nodes in a linked list and replaces items that match SEARCH and replaces them with REPLACE. When I try to "replace it" my codes does nothing...
I would really appreciate some help on the code that I already have.
Keep in mind the Node class is already created

```
public void replace(String search, String replace)
{
    Node current = first;

    if (size == 0)
        return;
    else
    {
        if (current.item.equals(search)) 
        {
            current.item = replace;
            current = current.next;
        }
        replace(search, replace); //Recursive call here
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you pass the children of the nodes to the recursive method?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to implement it using recursion, you must pass current node to the recursive method.

```
public void replace(String search, String replace) {
    replaceRecur(first, search, replace);
}

private void replaceRecur(Node cur, String search, String replace) {
    if (cur == null)
        return;
    if (cur.item.equals(search))
        cur.item = replace;
    replaceRecur(cur.next, search, replace);
}
```